# Is there server based html5 widget that will allow me to stream pulseaudio audio to a browser?

Tags: pulse-audio, html5

I have a Web based VPN running at home that I access from work and Pandora works pretty well since it's all HTML5, but other sites like Youtube and flash based media does not work since my VPN can't repackage and proxy flash.

I have a java based VNC viewer that lets me work on my desktop from home which is wrapped in my VPN's SSL, however I cannot hear anything playing on my computer since VNC does not wrap sound, at least not with my java viewer. My idea to pipe pulse audio from my Linux desktop to my linux web server and run a widget that any HTML5 compatible browser could stream live/slightly delayed audio.

I'm just not sure what to look for to get this working if it's at all possible